# When I run it the button doesn't do what It should

Tags: javascript, html, button

I don't know why the button doesn't work. What I want to do is that every Pokémon which "card" box is checked doesn't appear anymore when I click the button. and it does not work. I just started to code and you might smile while you read this. Its just all very confusing.

```js
function showUnowned() {
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[2].checked == true) {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>My Pokemon Card Collection</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Picture</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Pokedex Number</th>
    <th>Card</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- This is an example of how to add a Pokemon to the table. You can copy and paste this code for each Pokemon in your collection. -->
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png"></td>
    <td>Bulbasaur</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/2.png"></td>
    <td>Ivysaur</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/3.png"></td>
    <td>Venusaur</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/4.png"></td>
    <td>Charmander</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>



</table>
<button onclick="showUnowned()">Show Unowned Pokemon</button>
```

Comment: Array indexes are zero-based. Since there are two inputs in each row, the valid indexes are `[0]` and `[1]`. There's no `[2]`.

Comment: And change `var i = 0` to `var i = 1` since you can skip the first row

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the elements one more time (there are 4 elements but it loops 5 times), so you can edit your code to fix this :

```js
function showUnowned() {
  var rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    if (rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[2].checked == true) {
      rows[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to coding :)

I'll walk you through how you can resolve this.

**Step 1: Open some diagnostic tools.**
In this case, you can use the browser's console. Hit F12, Ctrl+Shift+I, or google how to open the developer tools for your browser. Once you've got the console open, perform the action that is giving you an issue.

In your case here, I saw the following error when clicking the button: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'checked')`

So, at some point in your code, the query you're using to find the `input` element is returning `undefined`. Basically, what you're expecting to find isn't there.

**Step 2: Deeper debugging**
Inside the developer tools you can click on the error and it will jump to the part of your code where the error is happening:
[image]

Set a breakpoint, run through the problem again and you'll be able to take a deeper look into what is happening when the error happens. IT's like being able to look into your code live while it is running. I'll leave you to google the finer parts of how to use a debugger.

**Step 3: Find the issue**
In your case, I saw that you were querying for an `input` element, but it doesn't exist in your first `tr`. So, on the first pass the query returns undefined and causes the error.

**The fix**
For this case I would recommend a simple check to ensure that the element exists before seeing if it is checked:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const unownedCheckbox = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[1] // changed this to index of 1 as there is no third checkbox

        if (!unownedCheckbox) continue

        if (unownedCheckbox.checked) {
            rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

With the check in place to ensure we have an element, we can safely call the `.checked` method. For more concise code, you can also use optional chaining:

```
        if (unownedCheckbox?.checked) {
            rows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
```

Cheers!